# How to increase product quantity in Ruby on Rails 4.2 on delivery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have app where I store products and their quantity, I've created controller delivery where I've got product_id and I have also value delivered.

So now after delivery I would love to update my product quantity. (Add value from delivery to the current value)

I was thinking to put this code to the create action in delivery controller but I don't know how?

```
 def create
@delivery= Delivery.new(delivery_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @delivery.save
    @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:ingredient_id])
    @ingredient.update_attributes(:quantity => :quantity + :delivered)
    ....
```

But It's not working that way. Maybe before save I need to find ingredient? Anything will help thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code (assuming that delivered quantity is stored in the `delivered` attribute):

```
@ingredient.quantity += @delivery.delivered
@ingredient.save
```

If you want to use exactly the `update_attributes` method:

```
@ingredient.update_attributes(quantity: (@ingredient.quantity + @delivery.delivered))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use increment!

eg

```
@ingredient.quantity.increment!
```

or if you need to increase by more than one

```
@ingredient.quantity.increment!(amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a basic remark, I would advise refactoring the Ingredient stuff out of the DelliveryController. You could do a after_save callback in the Delivery model for instance.

```
class Delivery < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :update_ingredients

  def update_ingredients
    // do the update here
  end
end
```

Probably you should even be thinkink about creating a seperate Object for handling this. Read this for inspiration: https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services